# Put all maps inside one list

Tags: arrays, flutter

My problem with `Flutter` is when I'm converting an array to a list, there is every item is a separated list and I want all the items in just one list.

Example output when putting 2 items:
  `[{title: ITEM1}, {title: ITEM2}]`

I want to put like this:
 `[{title: ITEM1, title: ITEM2}]`

I hope you guys understand the problem

```dart
  void _addPecas() {
    if ((_pecasController.text.isEmpty) ||
        ((_pecasController.text.trimLeft() == ("")))) {
      print("Campo Vazio");
    } else {
      setState(() {
        Map<String, dynamic> newPeca = Map();
        newPeca["title"] = _pecasController.text.trimLeft();
        _pecasController.text = "";
        _pecasList.add(newPeca);
        print(_pecasList);
      });
    }
  }
```

Comment: So you have an array (List in Dart) of objects (Map in Dart), each with a single element that is a title, correct? And you want to transform it a List that has a single Map with multiple elements, all titles?

Comment: @RenatoAbreu I provided an answer, please check and let me know if that what you are looking for.

Comment: @JoãoSoares yes, i guess.

Answer (score 0):

As I understood, you are asking for one `Map` inside `List` and add values into that `Map` and finally add it into a `List`. Here is how you can do it:

```
  Map<String, dynamic> newPeca = Map();
  if (_pecasController.text.isEmpty ||
      _pecasController.text.trimLeft() == ("")) { // you had too much unwanted brackets here
    print("Campo Vazio");
  } else {
    setState(() {
      newPeca["title"] = _pecasController.text.trimLeft(); // you have to have unique key if you want to keep in one Map. See the dart pad example I have provided a link below
      _pecasController.text = "";
      // _pecasList = [newPeca]; // this is also working without outside .add() but if the list is long, im not recommending this.
      print(_pecasList);
    });
  }
  // outside the iteration
  _pecasList.add(newPeca);
```

Edit simple dart example in [dartpad](https://dartpad.dartlang.org/791f022c90b7a38822fa77acf0781682)

Update:

Make sure this: `Map<String, dynamic> newPeca = Map();` outside the iteration. This way you are not creating Map for each and every iteration. You are adding to same map and that map you should add after each iteration to the `List` or just create empty list assign as a new list in each and every iteration(Btw, not the performant way).

Secondly, when you add to the list inside iteration each and every time map will add to the list.

Finally, Even if you make those right, your map will not take same value as title because the reason is your `key` of the map entry is `title` and you cannot have duplicate keys inside map and the list should be outside the iteration.

Comment: It didnt worked, it continues to create various maps just like it was before.

Comment: Oh Im sorry dear I forgot to say that out side the `_addPecas`

Comment: It stills separating... 

>I/flutter (30586): [{title: Item 2}, {title: Item 2}]

Comment: Yeah I got it sorry my bad. The reason is your `key` of the map entry is `title` and you cannot have duplicate keys inside map and the list should be outside the iteration.

Comment: @RenatoAbreu see this example I updated it now: https://dartpad.dartlang.org/791f022c90b7a38822fa77acf0781682

Comment: I took a look and it worked the way i want. But i dont know how to apply to my application since i'm not adding the items through a iteration (like your example) but for a function in a button bellow in the code (when i press the button i call the function _addPecas to add a new item).

Comment: Blasanka i finally got it. I will try the following: Use as "title" the  key title+listlenght (to make unique titles). I can't make it right now but i guess it will work.

Comment: @RenatoAbreu If you can provide relavent code snippet with what you have mention above comment. I will try my best to help.

Answer (score 0):

if `[{title: ITEM1, title: ITEM2}]` is what you want to achieve,

The problem here is that you are creating a new `Map` called `newPeca` every time your function runs. .

`Map<String, dynamic> newPeca = Map();`

So by the time you set your values you call `_pecasList.add(newPeca);` that new map will be appended to your List thus you get  `[{title: ITEM1}, {title: ITEM2}]`

Working with the assumption that you want only one Map in `_pecaList`, `_newPeca` should always reference that one Map

`Map<String, dynamic> newPeca = _pecaList[0]`

then you can add your desired values `newPeca["title"] = _pecasController.text.trimLeft();`

One more problem you'll run into, you want to have duplicate keys in the Map, which is not possible.
The newer value in the map will overwrite the existing one.
E.g

```
    newPeca[title] = "Item 1"
    newPeca[title] = "Item 2"
```

`newPeca[title]` will end up being `Item 2`

Comment: I understand the problem, so i guess i would need to make some modifications to work the way i need.